# How to sort a string in lexicographical order in bubble sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm given a problem statement were i need to sort based upon their love values of the respective lovers.

If love values is same for the two lovers, sorts their name lexicographically and chooses the lexicographically lesser named lover. How to perform this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
class test
{
  public static void bubble(String[] name,int[] a,int n)
  {
    //  int n=a.length;
      String temp_l;
      String temps;
      int[] name_l = new int[100000];

      int temp;
      for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
      {
            //n-i-1 for ignoring the element which has already used in comparison
            for(int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
            {
                if(a[j]>a[j+1])
                {
                    temp=a[j];
                    a[j] =a[j+1];
                    a[j+1]=temp;

            //Sort them according to their name
            temps=name[j];
            name[j]=name[j+1];
            name[j+1]=temps;
          }
            }
        temp_l = name[i];
        name_l[i]=temp_l.length();
      }



}
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=scan.nextInt();
    int t=scan.nextInt();
    String[] name= new String[100000];
    int[] length= new int[1000000];
    int[] love= new int[10000000];

    for (int i=0;i<n ;i++ ) {
      name[i]=scan.next();
      love[i]=scan.nextInt();
    }
    bubble(name,love,n);

    int[] name_l=new int[n];
    String temp;

      for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {

      temp = name[i];
      name_l[i]=temp.length();

      }



          //printing total t selection
          int test = n-1;
          for (int i=t;i>0;i--)
          {

              System.out.println(name[test]);
            test--;
          }

  }
}
```

**Sample Input:**

3 2

surbhi 3

surpanakha 3

shreya 5

**My output:**

shreya

surpanakha

**Expected Output**

shreya

surbhi

Please guide me to obtain the problem objective.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: You need to check more than one condition instead of just `if(a[j]>a[j+1])` to include a secondary sort criterion as described in your homework exercise...

Comment: Hint no2: please do **not** put your whole assignment into your question. We just need: your code, example input, output ... and where you see a problem. Thus: please turn to the help center to understand how to ask better questions. And instead of putting down the whole assignment, you better spent your time to property **format** your code. Because that is what really matters when you want others to help you!

Comment: How should be secondary sort criterion to perform  lexicographically sort and chooses the lexicographically lesser named word.?@fabian@GhostCat

Comment: @DineshSonachalam I have added code which you will need to add. Please mark correct and upvote if solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bubble sort method you have to add small code which will swap in case love scores are equal.

```
      for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;

                // Sort them according to their name
                temps = name[j];
                name[j] = name[j + 1];
                name[j + 1] = temps;
            }else if(a[j] == a[j + 1]){
                int result = name[j].compareTo(name[j + 1]);
                if(result < 0){
                    temps = name[j];
                    name[j] = name[j + 1];
                    name[j + 1] = temps;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I able to sort it  lexicographically but while choosing strings with lesser length, i am not getting a correct output. [link]([link](http://example.com) )

Comment: Added missing condition. (a[j] == a[j + 1])) It should work fine now

Comment: https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/october-easy-16/problems/6dd9fb1e-8-input-6dd9f4a.txt?Signature=x7Bd6cZicd3cpcyu3Gflwo6A6tg%3D&Expires=1475930561&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ

Comment: Above is the input

Comment: Output https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/october-easy-16/problems/6de4e63c-8-output-6de4e06.txt?Signature=sf0CT5yGnkVvGEfA6uohEF7MnwM%3D&Expires=1475930561&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ